# Create Isochrone along direction map of watershed in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, whitebox-tools

I am trying to generate a isochrone map starting from a map of the times to cross a single cell and a flow direction map. Basically, the final map has to provide, for each cell, the total time to reach the outlet of the watershed, which will be given by the sum of all the values in the cost map (i.e., the time map to cross a single cell) of the cells falling within the flow path provided by the flow direction.

To extract the path from a point to the outlet i can use a Whitebox tool  TraceDownslopeFlowPath and then through RasterCalculator I can sum all the values of my cost map of the cells along the path. However, this procedure should be repeated for all the cells of my raster.

Is there a procedure to follow or a tool that i can use?